# Update html tag class values based on Woocommerce product attribute dropdown selection

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, jquery, css

I have started to build a Woocommerce site, created a variable product with 2 product attributes for variations. The first product attribute is **"color"** and the second is **"size"**. I would like to add `.background-black` CSS class to my `#primary` Id when only the **"color"** product attribute has been changed and not **"size"**. I grabbed the attribute ID through the URL that is displayed in the cart once the variation is selected: `attribute_pa_color = black`.

What I would like to know is if there is a way I could do this using jQuery with woocommerce I just don't know how to do it properly. I appreciate the help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ("attribute_pa_color = black") {
        $("#primary").toggleClass("background-black");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to add/remove a customized class to `#primary` selector based on the selected product attribute "Color":

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
    var p = '#primary',
        c = $(p).prop('class'),
        s = 'select[name="attribute_pa_color"]';

    // On start
    if( $(s).val() !== '' ) {
        $(p).prop('class', 'background-'+$(s).val());
    }

    // On select (blur live event)
    $(s).blur( function() {
        var b = $(this).val() !== '' ? c+' background-'+$(this).val() : c;
        $(p).prop('class',b);
    });
});
</script>
```

Tested and works

---

You could also add directly a `color-background` CSS style instead to `#primary` selector, like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
    var p = '#primary',
        b = 'background-color',
        s = 'select[name="attribute_pa_color"]';

    // On start
    if( $(s).val() !== '' ) {
        $(p).css(b, $(s).val());
    }

    // On select (blur live event)
    $(s).blur( function() {
        if( $(this).val() !== '' )
            $(p).css(b, $(this).val());
        else
            $(p).removeProp('style');
    });
});
</script>
```

Tested and works too.